# Stepwise regression in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, regression

How to perform stepwise regression in GCP BigQueryML? The purpose is to identify which variables are significant and should be taken into consideration for creating statistical models.

Could not find any documentation on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the BQML explanation with the command `ML.GLOBAL_EXPLAIN` which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-global-explain)

For each feature, you have an attribution value that explain the influence of the feature on the model inference/prediction.